# Is there a way to customized a fix width of Entry box in Xamarin forms?

Tags: xml, forms, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Entry box will have various width depending on mobile device, is there a way to set width constant?

I'm using margins right now to make them smaller width.

```
<StackLayout>
<Label Text="Add Drain Output(s)" TextColor="Fuchsia" 
FontFamily="Times" />
<Entry x:Name="data1Entry" WidthRequest="100" />
<Label x:Name="drain1Label" />
<Label x:Name="drain2Label" />

<Entry x:Name="data2Entry" WidthRequest="50" />`
```

Comment: have you tried WidthRequest?

Comment: i ran it both are still the same size..

Comment: Set horizontal option for the entry as Start and width request as well.

Comment: Horizontal Option got it to work on how it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to specify **HorizontalOptions** with the **WidthRequest** to get this to work on a **StackLayout** as it will attempt to auto-expand by default.

you could change like this:

```
<Entry x:Name="data1Entry" WidthRequest="100"  HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use padding or you can create a grid with some column and put your entry control inside column